# Validity in IRT Style

Tags: item-response-theory, validity

From my reading, I found that IRT generally provides more sophisticated information.
Therefore, in regards of unidimensional 3PL IRT model, how should I report the finding about validity in dichotomous items as compared to CTT?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should be more precise in your question because for me it sounds like "how to use IRT in general". Refering to one of multiple handooks could help, e.g. http://www.amazon.com/Response-Theory-Psychologists-Multivariate-Applications/dp/0805828192 or Google search provides multiple short tutorials and introductions to IRT: https://www.google.pl/search?q=validity+irt

Comment: I don't think the 3PL provides any more information than any other IRT model, but it *could* account for guessing affects to help un-bias estimates of $\theta$ at a later time when the test is scored. So it's not really a validity question, but one of practicality which should be supported by evidence.